# Foreign Time to Local Time

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I'm trying to convert foreign time to Local Time. I'm getting a date and time in `Europe/London`. Currently I'm using moment-timezone to get my code working, however its giving me a wrong output.

```
resultDate = new moment('2017-06-30T22:10:00').tz('Europe/London').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

I think the code thinks that the date input is already in local time where I need to convert it into `Europe/London` which would give a local result, where as what I want is to actually convert the foreign time to local time.

In short the date and time as my input (`2017-06-30T22:00:00`), I am expecting it to be 7 hours in advance (`2017-07-1T05:00:00`) since I currently live in `Asia/Manila`, 7 hours in advance to London. However I'm getting `2017/06/30 15:00:00 +0100` as my result.

Is there a way for me to do this by utilizing the information `'Europe/London'` or `'Asia/Manila'` as seen in my code?

Comment: Try postfixing it with 'Z' to enfore that your input datetime string is in UTC00, like:  resultDate = new moment('2017-06-30T22:10:00Z').tz('Europe/London').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

Comment: @LajosGallay - I've tried doing as you have mentioned. It gave me a different result, however still a wrong output. It gave me 2017-06-30 23:00:00

Comment: @Light `2017-06-30T22:10:00` is time in London, in Manila or in local time? What is your desired output? Input converted to time in London, to time in Manila or to local time?

Comment: @VincenzoC - 2017-06-30T22:10:00 is the time in London. I want that time to be converted to Manila time. However as stated above, the code considers the time as Manila time already, and subtracts 7 hours from it. I apologize if this is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) to parse your input as `Europe/London` time and then use the [`tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) function to convert it to `Asia/Manila`.

The first parses your input using the given timezone while the latter convert a moment objet to a given timezone.

Here a working sample:

```js
// Parse input considering as London tz
var timeInLondon = moment.tz('2017-06-30T22:10:00', 'Europe/London');
// Converting input to Manila
var timeInManila = timeInLondon.tz('Asia/Manila');
// Show result
console.log(timeInManila.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer however, I'm still not getting the correct result. This is the output I'm getting '2017-06-30 22:10:00'

Comment: 2017-06-30T22:10:00 is the time in London. I want that time to be converted to Manila time. However as stated above, the code considers the time as Manila time already, and subtracts 7 hours from it. I apologize if this is confusing.