# Convert a specific date and time between locations using Moment.js version 2.0.0+

Tags: date, timezone, momentjs

How do I change a date time string that represents a New York, New York date and time to Melbourne Australia using Moment.js 2.0.0+ ?

---

Other answers I found on StackOverflow were outdated or slightly different than my use case.

```
convert this string '2016-04-28 09:30:00' to its Melbourne Australia equivalent
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply:

```
var s = moment.tz('2016-04-28 09:30:00',      // input date time string
                  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',      // format of input
                  'America/New_York')         // time zone of input

              .tz('Australia/Melbourne')      // convert to another time zone

              .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); // format output string
```

Answer (score 0):

### The solution I found is posted below

**set the time zone** to convert from

```
moment.tz.setDefault('America/New_York');
```

**create the moment object** with **date and time** as well as **date format** and
**set the timezone** of the date

```
var ny = moment('2016-04-28 09:30:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').tz('America/New_York');
```

**clone the original** time and date then **change the time zone**

```
var mel = ny.clone().tz('Australia/Melbourne');
```

use the **.format()** function to see the date in the console

```
mel.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: Note that moment-timezone has a [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) method that you can use to parse specifying timezone (so you can avoid `moment.tz.setDefault`). See an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43776940/4131048).

Comment: Also, you parsed the hours wrong - use `HH`, not `hh`.  And you probably want to use `format` instead of `toString`.  And, if you don't use the original moment for anything else, cloning it is optional.

Comment: @Matt Johnson thanks for the corrections and the example. I've chosen your answer as the solution, but will leave my corrected answer as another, albeit more verbose solution for others to reference.

Comment: @VincenzoC Matt Johnson's answer shows an example of your recommendation thanks for the feedback.