# Convert moment object to particular time zone using tz()

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have input data `"2017-06-01 06:00:00"` and here I need to convert time object to particular time zone, how can I achieve it?

I tried:

```
convert_time: function(date_begin, date_end){
    var tz = "Asia/Kolkata"
    return moment(date_begin).format("DD.MM.YYYY") +
           ' : ' +
           moment.utc(date_begin).format("HH:mm Z") +
           " - " +
           moment.utc(date_end).tz(tz).format("HH:mm Z")
}
```

But I can't convert to my zone.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I cant acieve the result"*? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @TJ No errors, I can't convert to my zone

Comment: Which is the timezone of your input? Maybe these question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43776161/4131048) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/44043069/4131048) can help you.